# postback on click for type ahead drop down

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, postback, typeahead

I have a type a head drop down list that I created. Clearly I had to turn the AutoPostBack to false because otherwise it would post back as the user was typing. But I want to poast back when use has made his selection.

I don't wanna use a submit button or anything like that. Long story, just trust me it's not the solution for my situation.

In the javascript that does the type ahead when the use clicks enter I post back. That work great.

However whast about when the user click with the mouse? So I use the onblur event to postback. However that requires clicking outside of the drop down list.

I want the postback to happen when they click the new item. So like a postback when itemchanged, but only if I changed it by clicking on it.

Any ideas???

Comment: No ideas? I'm still looking for a solution...

Comment: Using onblur for a postback is dangerous, in that anything that causes your control to lose focus will cause a postback.

Comment: Yes. I agree, because even if you click the ddl and then click off it will postback. But while this is anoying, it has no adverse effect on the web app and beats using on selectionChanged because then the type ahead wont work. But i'm open for other suggestions all together...?

Answer (score 0):

Providing your using an up to date version of Type Ahead, the library actually comes with a set of callback functions which are available [here.](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md#custom-events)

To execute a callback, just pass it in via a bind method when you initialize type ahead. Example code:

```
        // attach type-ahead to class
        $autoComplete.typeahead({
            hint: true,
            highlight: true,
            minLength: 1
        }, {
            displayKey: 'value',
            source: substringMatcher($autoCompleteData)
        }).bind("typeahead:selected", function (obj, datum, name) {
            console.log(obj, datum, name);
        });
```

The .bind method on the end will execute when the user either clicks an option or hits the return key on an option. Replace the console.log entry with whatever you want to do, i.e target a submit button a trigger a click.